# Configuring SpringSource Tool Suite wth AspectJ

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

How can I configure the SpringSource Tool Suite(ver 2.3.0) Spring project to accept `.aj` (AspectJ) file?

Currently it does not recognize `.aj` file.

And I cannot add `*.aj` file because it's a Spring project, not an AspectJ project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring project can be an AspectJ project at the same time.

To configure your project as AspectJ right-click your project in Eclipse, select `Configure/Convert To AspectJ project`.
Additionally you can enable Spring Aspect Tooling by selecting `Spring Tools/Enable Spring Aspect Tooling`

Comment: I converted my project into AspectJ project. Thanks!